# Creating stored queries programmatically with vb.net, odbc and access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

i have developed a small ms-access based software with vb.net.

I've added auto-update capabilities to the software (mostly by using clickonce) to simplify the release of new features.

Every version of the software executes the update routine which may update also the existing database.
Lately i've made few changes on the database structure adding few stored queries, so i want the autoupdate code to programmatically add these new queries to the existing database and make it perfectly up to date.

I haven't already found a solution to add stored queries to an ms-access database using odbc...
I also tried to use the "CREATE PROC" sql statement but it does not seem to work with access databases, even if i create the query form the Microsoft Office Access front-end.
I've found some examples that uses ADODB, but i'm using odbc to remain both x86 and x64 compliant.

PS: sorry for my bad english... I hope i've been clear enough

Comment: I don't know why i got a -1 -.-

Comment: My advice is to use SQL Server Express. It's free, doesn't require people to have an Office license, will do what you want easily, and is clearly more powerful than Access.

Comment: Thanks @IanC , I really appreciate your suggestion but the kind of software that i developed is not a regular database-driven software. Often my client need to move the whole software from a computer to another and obviously he cannot lose his data. So i thought the best way to satisfy his needs is to use a file based database that can easily stored on a mobile device. I also tought to use an external online database, but my client is not always connected to internet. So i had no other choice than a file based db...

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, why don't you look at SQL Lite? It is designed for mobile, yet scales well for larger loads. And it's free, with source code even. Perhaps it can better fit your needs.

Comment: It sounds to me like a cloud solution would also fit. What many developers do is use SQL Lite on the client side, and a larger RDBMS on the server. For example, SQL Lite is natively supported by Adobe AIR, so you can store temporal data locally, and store what you need on the server (aka cloud).

Comment: SqLite could be a nice solution, probably it's faster and more scalable than access. But switching the whole software to sqLite would be a big effort now and i need to push the new version as soon as possible. The other solutions you suggested (local storage and network sync) would be really good, but a little bit complex and not as easy to implement. For the moment i think i'll adopt this solution: Create a blank database with all the up-to-date stored queries and copy the old data to this new "template" database... probably a raw and not so efficient solution but it will do the trick.

Comment: @IanC I had no more charachters to say you "Thanks" again :P

Comment: What you suggest will work, too. And since you want to push the app out, go for it! :)

Comment: @Luciano, don't forget that on Stack Overflow, we have a tradition of voting for comments / answers that are useful. It helps build community. I'm not saying this to ask for votes, but because I notice you have only voted 8 times.

Answer (score 1):

Stored queries in Jet/ACE are of two types, SELECT queries and what Access calls "Action" queries. SELECT queries correspond to VIEWS and action queries to SPROCs. So, if it's a DML statement, you'd create it as an SPROC, while if it's a SELECT, as a VIEW.

The one thing I'm not sure of is how parameters interact with this. I don't use Jet/ACE except from Access, so this is not something that I'm experienced with doing, so don't really have the answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can set a reference to DAO (which is actually much "closer to the metal" of Jet/ACE than ADO is), check the `CreateQueryDef` method and the `QueryDefs` collection.